# Trying to add swipe up/down animation between cards (Flutter)

Tags: user-interface, animation, flutter

I am working on an app for flashcards, I have a FlipCard animation widget to flip the card over when I swipe left or right. But I am trying to add an animation when I swipe up and down. I would like the animation to scroll up/down to the next list item, just the card (inside the yellow box), not the whole page to change or not to pop to a new page.

I currently swipe up/down and the next list item appears, but I would like the smooth animation scrolling of the card instead of the text suddenly appearing.

Any ideas for what Widget(s) I should use?

[Current Page](https://gallery.mailchimp.com/10006fe83474a3934f34cff94/images/9c170753-a1f2-437b-907c-670ae4cee531.png)

Comment: You can use PageView with vertical axis

Answer (score 0):

You could investigate if PageView suits your needs. It provides smooth transitions between its children widgets.

You may find [this article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/a-deep-dive-into-pageview-in-flutter-with-custom-transitions-581d9ea6dded) on PageViews useful.

Comment: Thanks mate, i'll try that. The article link doesn't seem to work, its says "about:blank#blocked"?

Comment: https://medium.com/flutter-community/a-deep-dive-into-pageview-in-flutter-with-custom-transitions-581d9ea6dded